# Como compilo el motor de javascript v8 en ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu

Estoy intentando compilar javascript `v8` en `ubuntu 16.10` pero no he podido, he buscado en google y no solo he encontrado como compilarlo con `scons` y con `GYP`, pero al parecer ya no se puede usar `GYP`, encontré como compilarlo usando `gn` pero no he podido hacerlo.

Ya he descargado `v8.git` y `depot_tools`, tengo un directorio llamado `v8` en el que tengo los directorios `v8` y `depot_tools` con su respectivo contenido.

En las instrucciones de compilación de `v8`, dice que hay que ejecutar:

```
$ gclient sync
```

Cuando ejecuto eso, la terminal me devuelve este error:

```
Error: client not configured; see 'gclient config'
```

La verdad no se como configurar `gclient`.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que que pretendes hacer?

Comment: Hola, intento extender el API de v8 y añadir algunas funciones propias.

Answer (score 0):

Instala nodeJs, ya incluye V8 en su compilador

> sudo apt-get install nodejs

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder, de hecho ya tengo instalado nodejs y sinceramente quiero extender el API de v8 y añadir algunas funciones para que esten disponibles en el contexto global de javascript en un documento HTML, pero para hacer eso creo que necesito compilarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Es.Stackoverflow, para compilar tu archivo simplemente utiliza:  node miarchivo.js desde tu terminal. Te recomiendo ver videos-tutoriales acerca de node y en especial de MeteorJS

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero realmente con eso solo ejecuto 'miarchivo.js' haciendo uso de nodejs, sin embargo lo que realmente estoy intentando hacer es compilar el propio v8 y generar un ejecutable con las funciones estandar de javascript.

Answer (score -1):

siguiendo los pasos de https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-from-Source

> instalar depot tools

```
~/Code > git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

> agregamos depot tools al path

```
~/Code > pwd
/home/alejandro/Code
~/Code > export PATH=$PATH:/home/alejandro/Code/depot_tools
```

> Don’t simply git clone the V8 repository!

```
~/Code > fetch v8
~/Code > cd v8
~/Code/v8 > gclient sync
```

En linux sólo una vez, instalar y generar dependencias (puede pedir clave sudo)

```
~/Code/v8 > ./build/install-build-deps.sh
```

Si este paso da error por red inestable, correr un `fix-missing` y repetir:

```
~/Code/v8 > sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
~/Code/v8 > ./build/install-build-deps.sh
```

Generar build files

```
~/Code/v8 > tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release
```

Luego para compilar:

```
~/Code/v8 > ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
```

Correr los tests:

```
~/Code/v8 > tools/run-tests.py --gn
```